# Asynchronous call using NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am hitting some URL from my nodeJS application,
    URL  --> Time Taken
    url1 --> 3 sec
    url2 --> 4 sec
    url3 --> 2 sec

and i am saving the result in one common variable named global using promises. if i am doing it synchronously it is taking 9 secs(4+3+2).

Is there a way I can save the output asynchronously of all the three variables in one variable, such that i need to wait only 4 secs[max of all urls time.].

Currently, my approach is not waiting for others to finish and returning me null, if i am trying asynchronously.

Comment: What are you using to make the call? Any Promises?

Comment: if i am trying promises, it is taking a long time, i have directly put it into for loop.

Comment: Then which function / package?

Comment: var https = require('https');  i was making all the call through https only.

Answer (score 1):

Learn [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com)

Then use this

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var urls = ["http://", "http://",...];


Promise.map(urls, function(url){    // executes concurrently
    return request(url)
}).then(function(resultsArray){
    // resultsArray = array of all results
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Wainage. I will try this. :)